# How To Get Current Logged in User Data in React Native Using Laravel Auth Sanctum API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-native

I am using Laravel API as a backend for my react-native application. I want to get all the logged in user's data from the users table when he logs in.

I've tried several things but nothing has worked so far.

Here is my code:

Laravel api.php:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});// i also tried this code.


Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user(); 
   });
```

ProfileScreen.js

```
 const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_token');
      axios.get("/api/user").then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)//this is logging nothing.
       
      }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error' + e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  });
```

Comment: just use `auth()->user()` to get logged in user object

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(res);`?

Answer (score 1):

`auth()->user()` is a global helper, `Auth::user()` is a support facade,
and  `$request->user()` uses http.

You can use any of them. For a quick test, try

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return auth()->user();
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Be sure to send your token in a header like so:

```
 Authorization: Bearer UserTokenHere
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what would i write in my react native application in the profile screen to get this user's data to be able to access them in the application?

Comment: No, this is not reactjs and i am not creating a browser, i am creating an application with ReactNative. please read my question carefully and what i am trying to do. everything in the video you commented i already know and have already done. Please edit your question to solve the problem as you did not provide anything new that i havent already included in my question. Thank you